# Ionic run android error

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I just installed ionic but when I try `ionic emulate android` in the cmd window, I get the following error:

> Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory > 'C:\Users...\myapp\plugins\com.ionic.keyboard\www\keyboard.js

I have tried deleting the project and creating a new one, uninstalling ionic and cordova and reinstalling them, amongst other attempts at fixing the problem and I have not had any success. I looked in the directory in the error message and everything is there until `\www\keyboard.js`. There is no `www` folder.

Also, I'm running windows 8. If anyone has any idea how to fix this I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you are missing the [`com.ionic.keyboard`](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugins-keyboard) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

just create the "www" folder, and retry running `ionic emulate android`

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but the problem is still there. I also tried cordova plugin add com.ionic.keyboard, but it says that it is already installed

Comment: also copy [this keyboard.js](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugins-keyboard/blob/master/www/keyboard.js) file inside, after you create `...\myapp\plugins\com.ionic.keyboard\www`